# How to write in-place extension-function

Tags: kotlin, extension-function

```
fun String.reversed():String{
// return another String..no 
prob
}

fun String.reverse(){
//in-place change this
}
```

How to write the String.reverse()?

Comment: Strings are immutable: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/immutability.html

Comment: ok change example to MutableList.myfunc(). The point is it has to be an in-place function like reverse() instead of reversed()

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: fun String.reversed():String{
    return this.toMutableList().reversed().joinToString(separator = "")
    
}

Comment: I mean in-place attempt.

Comment: fun main(args: Array<String>) {
var s=mutableListOf('a','b','c')
 s.myReverse()
 println(s)
}


fun MutableList<Char>.myReverse(){
    with(this){
    reverse()    
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check how the in-place extension function `reverse` is implemented for `MutableList` in the Kotlin codebase: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.3.50/libraries/stdlib/js/src/generated/_CollectionsJs.kt#L20

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.reverse(): Unit {
    val midPoint = (size / 2) - 1
    if (midPoint < 0) return
    var reverseIndex = lastIndex
    for (index in 0..midPoint) {
        val tmp = this[index]
        this[index] = this[reverseIndex]
        this[reverseIndex] = tmp
        reverseIndex--
    }
}
```

In general, you take `this` instance and call mutating methods on it to modify its content in place.

However, `String` class is immutable: it doesn't provide methods to modify its content in place, and, therefore, you cannot write an extension that modifies a string in place either.